# Хранение связей нескольких таблиц в одной таблице

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

В программе существует около 30-ти таблиц, которые относятся к разным документам.
Необходимо добавить возможность, позволяющую связать записи этих таблиц между собой.

Правильным ли будет хранение всех эти связей в одной таблице?
Т.е. схема таблицы будет выглядеть примерно так:

- document_type
- document_id
- related_document_type
- related_document_id

Какие недостатки у этого способа помимо отсутствия возможности добавления внешних ключей?

Comment: Неясна схема связей. Каждый документ может быть связан строго с 1 таблицей? Или может быть связан и с несколькими? Документу соответствует строго 1 запись связанной таблицы? или может быть несколько из одной таблицы? *Какие недостатки у этого способа* Крайне геморройная шаблонизация запросов.

Comment: "Каждый документ может быть связан строго с 1 таблицей? Или может быть связан и с несколькими?"

> С несколькими.

"Документу соответствует строго 1 запись связанной таблицы? или может быть несколько из одной таблицы?"

> Несколько.

А что подразумеваете под шаблонизацией запросов?

Comment: Меня, например, смущает, что у вас разные таблицы для разных типов документов. Ответ будет зависеть от того, что это за таблицы и как данные в них связаны друг с другом. Вплоть до того, что одним из возможных вариантов будет объединить все 30 таблиц в одну и добавить туда поле "тип документа".

Comment: "Меня, например, смущает, что у вас разные таблицы для разных типов документов."  
К сожалению, эти таблицы созданы давно.  

Вплоть до того, что одним из возможных вариантов будет объединить все 30 таблиц в одну и добавить туда поле "тип документа"

Comment: И эти таблицы никак не связаны между собою.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанию, у тебя схема многие ко многим:

- Типы документов к документам
- Относительные типы документов к
  относительным документам.

Исходя их этого предложенная тобой связи возможна, но является не совсем верной с точки зрения архитектуры БД. Я рекомендовал бы разделить на 3 таблицы. Если основной сущностью является документ, то это выглядело бы так :

document_type
document_id

related_document_type
related_document_id

document_id
related_document_id